Upper bound for Gamma function in Tenenbaum's book
I am recently reading Tenenbaum's monograph Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory. When I am studying the Chapter of Euler Gamma function, I encounter this exercise:

Show that for all $\sigma\ge\frac{1}{2}$, there is a constant $M_0(\sigma)$ such that: $$|\Gamma(x+iy)|\le M_0(\sigma)e^{-|y|},\quad\forall y\in\Bbb R,\,x\in\left[\frac{1}{2},\sigma\right]$$

I can find a similar result using Stirling's formula presented as follows (the method comes from Lemma 3 in this arXiv article https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.00635):
$$
\Gamma(s) \ll |t|^{\sigma - 1/2} e^{-\pi |t|/2}
$$
holds whenever $\sigma$ lies in a fixed interval.
By Stirling's formula, we know that when $\sigma$ lies in a fixed interval
$$
\log \Gamma(s) = \left(s - \frac{1}{2}\right)\log s - s + O(1)
$$
$$
= \left(s - \frac{1}{2}\right)\log(it) + \left(s - \frac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(1 + \frac{\sigma}{it}\right) - s + O(1)
$$
$$
= \left(s - \frac{1}{2}\right)\log(it) + it \log\left(1 + \frac{\sigma}{it}\right) - s + O(1)
$$
$$
= \left(s - \frac{1}{2}\right)\log(it) - it + O(1)
$$
Taking real parts on both sides, we see that as $t \rightarrow +\infty$ there is
$$
\log|\Gamma(s)| = \left(\sigma - \frac{1}{2}\right)\log t - \frac{\pi t}{2} + O(1) \tag{1}
$$
Therefore, exponentiating on both sides of (1) yields the desired result.
However, this desired result $$
\Gamma(s) \ll |t|^{\sigma - 1/2} e^{-\pi |t|/2}
$$ still differ from what appears in this exercise as the constant $M_{0}(\sigma)$ is independent from the imaginary part $t$. I wonder anyone can give any hint in solving this exercise? Thanks!

Welcome to the site. I took the time to edit in some LaTex for the problem statement; it’s good to rely on links as little as possible, answerers should be able to see your question clearly in the body.
